# Uniformly distributed probability error

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm having trouble with the following question:

> The error for the production of a machine is uniformly distributed over $[-0.7, 0.5]$ unit. Assuming that there are $10$ machines working at the same time, approximate the probability that the final total production differ from the exact total production by more than $1$ unit?

I've attempted this multiple times and failed to get the correct answer. See the image below for my solution reaching 0.033625.

Any advice on where I'm going wrong and what I should be doing instead would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

[image: Solution attempt]
[image: Solution attempt 2]

Comment: Despite the praise below for providing details, we frown upon the use of images, unless vital (e.g., geometry).  Please do your best to use text and  [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?r=SearchResults&s=11|38.1878) in questions.  Images can disappear, links rot over time.  This site is an archive, as well as a Q&A site.  Your post above would be rather easy to type, and equations will be formatted with on or two $-signs on each end. Just the effort, even if not perfect, will be well received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requested probability that the error in production is greater than 1 means that

$$\mathbb{P}[|\Sigma X|>1]=\mathbb{P}[|Z|>1.826]=2\times 0.034.$$

...also an error of -2 even differs from exact production by more than 1 unit.

Comment: Correct method, but there is confusion about the standard deviation of the sum. Should be $\sigma_T=\sqrt{1,2},$